Stock price prediction using astrology
Is there a system to predict the value of futures, options, stocks, mutual funds and other such securities through Jyotisha Shastra?
As Hora Shastra part of Jyotisha Shastra deals with timely predictions, can anything be said about the securities related to a particular company or companies? Thanks beforehand.
